# How to increase size of disk partition in Linux?

Tags: partitioning

I want to increase size of my disk partition in which my Ubuntu OS is installed. I have another free partition available but I don't see any option to merge these two or increase size.

I have heard about GParted but don't know how exactly does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you delete the second partition, gparted will then allow the free space to extend the existing partition, assuming that the partition you want to extend and the now free space, are contiguous.

Answer (score 0):

try to use gparted, select the free space and select create a new partition

Comment: Thank you for your answer but gparted allows to create a new partition. it doesnt allows me to add this new partition to my /home drive as I wish to extend size of the that drive.